# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\ln^2(\sin x)\textrm{d}x$ in a different way?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, alternative-proof, polylogarithm, digamma-function

The following problem

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x\ln^2(\sin x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{19}{32}\zeta(4)+\frac{1}{24}\ln^4(2)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag1$$

was already solved in [this solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292272)

The [question](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3209159789180797&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater) here is how to prove $(1)$ by utilizing the Fourier series of

$$\tan x\ln(\sin x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-\frac1n\right)\sin(2nx)$$

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1+t}t^{n-1}dt\right)\sin(2nx),\quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I wonder what kind of clever manipulation we need to do to create the integrand in $(1)$. I am sure it would be an amazing solution.

Thank you in advance.

---

This Fourier series can be found in the book, **Almost Impossible Integrals, Sums and series**, page $243$,  Eq$(3.281)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Potenzen_des_Arkussinus) we have

$$\frac23\arcsin^4x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^{(2)}(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^4{2n\choose n}}$$

Set $x=1$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n^4{2n\choose n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^nH_{n}^{(2)}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}-\frac{15}{4}\zeta(4)\tag1$$

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3793529) we showed
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^nH_n}{n^3{2n\choose n}}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}+12\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)\tag2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n^4{2n\choose n}}=12\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{15}{4}\zeta(4)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^nH_n}{n^3{2n\choose n}}$$

By using the Fourier series of $\tan x\ln(\sin x)$, we showed in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792648):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^nH_n}{n^3{2n\choose n}}=-8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\zeta(4)+8\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{3}\ln^4(2)$$

substitute this result we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n^4{2n\choose n}}=8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{19}{4}\zeta(4)+4\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{3}\ln^4(2)\tag3$$

Now we use the well-known series expansion of $\arcsin^2 x$:

$$\arcsin^2(x)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n x^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}$$

Multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln x}{x}$ then $\int_0^1$ and use that $-\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln xdx=\frac{1}{4n^2}$ we get

$$\frac18\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n^4{2n\choose n}}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arcsin^2(x)}{x}dx$$

$$\overset{IBP}{=}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\overset{x=\sin\theta}{=}\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln^2(\sin x)dx\tag4$$

From $(3)$ and $(4)$ we obtain

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} x\ln^2(\sin x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{19}{32}\zeta(4)+\frac{1}{24}\ln^4(2)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: (+1) Very nice approach!

Comment: @user97357329 thank you. I just got lucky with this integral.

Comment: (+50) This kind of 'luck' is always desired and must be awarded.

Comment: @user97357329 thank you for the points :)

Answer (score 6):

Some generalizations. Enjoy!

- $\small \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} x^3 \log ^2(2 \sin (x)) \, dx=-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(\bar 5,1)+\frac{3}{4} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{3 \zeta (3)^2}{8}+\frac{21}{32} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{187 \pi ^6}{26880}+\frac{1}{32} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)-\frac{1}{32} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$
- $\small \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} x^3 \log^3 (2 \sin (x)) \, dx=\frac{9}{4} \zeta(\bar5,1,1)+\frac{9}{4} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{9}{4} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)-\frac{\pi ^4 \zeta (3)}{16}-\frac{759 \pi ^2 \zeta (5)}{512}-\frac{45 \zeta (7)}{512}+\frac{63}{64} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)+\frac{3}{40} \pi ^2 \log ^5(2)-\frac{1}{16} \pi ^4 \log ^3(2)$
- $\scriptsize \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} x^4 \log ^4(2 \sin (x)) \, dx=-\frac{7}{4} \pi ^3 \zeta(\bar5,1)-15 \pi \zeta(\bar7,1)-6 \pi  \zeta(\bar5,1,\bar1,1)+9 \pi  \log ^2(2)\zeta(\bar5,1)+18 \pi  \log (2) \zeta(\bar5,1,1)-24 \pi  \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \zeta (3)-\frac{1}{6} \pi ^5 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+6 \pi ^3 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+3 \pi ^3 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log ^2(2)+6 \pi ^3 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)+\frac{3 \pi ^3 \zeta (3)^2}{8}+\frac{2835 \pi  \zeta (3) \zeta (5)}{64}+\frac{1}{5} \pi  \zeta (3) \log ^5(2)+\frac{13}{24} \pi ^3 \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)-\frac{31}{8} \pi  \zeta (5) \log ^3(2)+\frac{9}{2} \pi  \zeta (3)^2 \log ^2(2)-\frac{8}{15} \pi ^5 \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{65}{32} \pi ^3 \zeta (5) \log (2)+\frac{465}{16} \pi  \zeta (7) \log (2)-\frac{36493 \pi ^9}{4838400}+\frac{1}{12} \pi ^3 \log ^6(2)-\frac{5}{72} \pi ^5 \log ^4(2)+\frac{25 \pi ^7 \log ^2(2)}{1008}$

Comment: (+1) They are definitely enjoyable, and more enjoyable by the art of mathematics.

Comment: @AliShather   These are known as alternating [multiple zeta values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) (MZV). For example, $$\zeta(\bar{5},1,1) = \sum_{n_1 > n_2 > n_3 \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n_1}}{n_1^5 n_2 n_3}$$ the bar indicates which summation is alternating. The number $5+1+1 = 7$ is called weight of this MZV.

Comment: @pisco thank you for clarifying thats what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this integral use the following integral which can be proved using contour integration.

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}(\cos^{p-1}x )\cos(ax)dx=\frac{π}{2^p}\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma(\frac {p+a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac {p-a+1}{2})}$$

On differentiating with respect to $a$, we get

$$\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x(\cos^{p-1}x )\sin(ax)dx=\frac{π}{2^p}\Gamma(p)\frac{\psi(\frac {p+a+1}{2})-\psi(\frac {p-a+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac {p+a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac {p-a+1}{2})}$$

where $p>0$ and $ -(p+1)<a<(p+1)$ and $\Gamma(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are the gamma and  digamma functions.Let $p_1=(\frac {p+a+1}{2})$ and $p_2=(\frac {p-a+1}{2})$.On differentiating the above equation.

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}I(a,p)=\frac{π}{2^{p+1}}\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma(p_1)\Gamma(p_2)}[-(\psi(p_1)-\psi(p_2))^2+\psi'(p_1)+\psi'(p_2)]$$$$=\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x^2(cos^{p-1}x )\cos(ax)dx$$

On putting $a=0$, we get

$$J_p=\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x^2(\cos^{p-1}x )dx=\frac{π}{2^{p+1}}\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma^2(\frac{p+1}{2})}\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})$$

Again differentiating with respect to parameter $p$ ,we get

$$\frac d {dp}J_p=\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x^2(\cos^{p-1}x)\log(\cos x)dx=\frac{π}{2^{p+1}}\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma^2(\frac{p+1}{2})}\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})[-\log2+\psi(p)-\psi(\frac{p+1}{2})+\frac {\psi''(\frac{p+1}{2})}{\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})}$$

From the above integral we can also calculate below integral by letting $p=1$.

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x^2\log(\cos x)dx=\frac{π^3}{24}[-\log2+\frac{\psi''(1)}{\psi'(1)}]=-\frac{π^3}{24}\log2-\fracπ2 \zeta(3)$$

Now, $$J''_p=\int_{0}^{\frac π 2}x^2(\cos^{p-1}x)\log^2(\cos x)dx=\frac{π}{2^{p+1}}\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma^2(\frac{p+1}{2})}\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})
\left ( \left (  [-\log2+\psi(p)-\psi(\frac{p+1}{2})+\frac {\psi''(\frac{p+1}{2})}{\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})}
\right )^2+\psi'(p)-\frac12\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})+\frac12\frac d {dp}\frac {\psi''(\frac{p+1}{2})}{\psi'(\frac{p+1}{2})} \right ) $$

On letting $p=1$ ,we get

> $$\int_{0}^{\fracπ2}x^2\log^2(\cos x)dx=\fracπ {1440}[11π^4+60π^2\log^2 2+720\zeta(3)\log2]$$

Now you can get your desired integral using all of the above integrals but this is lenghty task as it involves some other integrals which will create polylogarithms and the term containing $ \zeta(3)$ will cancel.

These are some generalisations of log-sine integrals:

---

> $$\int_0^zx^m\log\left(2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{z^{m+1}}{m+1}\log\left(2\sin\frac{z}{2}\right)-\frac{z^{m+1}}{(m+1)^2}+\frac{2z^{m+1}}{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2k)}{m+2k+1}\left(\frac{z}{2\pi}\right)^{2k} \;\;\;\;\; (|z|<2\pi;m\in\mathbb{N}).$$

> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(2\sin\frac12 \theta\right)^{\lambda}e^{i\nu\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta=2\pi e^{i\nu\pi}\frac{\Gamma(1+\lambda)}{\Gamma(1+\frac12\lambda+\nu)\Gamma(1+\frac12\lambda-\nu)}.$$

> $$2^p\int_0^\pi x^n\log^p(\sin (x))\mathrm{d}x=\pi^n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}^p}{\mathrm{d}m^p}\left(\left.\frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{4^m}\right)\right|_{m=0}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^p}{\partial m^p}\left(\left.\frac{\binom{2m}{m+k}}{4^m}\right)\right|_{m=0}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{n!(-1)^{j+k}}{(n+1-2j)!(2\pi)^{2j-1}k^{2j}}\right).$$

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\log\left(2\sin \frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{2}a_n\ \ \ \ \ (n\in N_0)\\[2ex] \text{coefficients $a_n$ are given by:}\\[2ex] \frac{2^{-2z}\Gamma\left(\frac12-z\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\ \Gamma(1-z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$

---

Comment: Excuse for this comment. There are a lot of the command of log, sin, cos etc. without \.

Comment: @sebastiano I'm not much familiar with Latex commands now but I'll try to improve it in the future.

Comment: Mine was by no means a criticism. It was a recommendation. :-)

Comment: I'm not taking it as criticism but as advice

Comment: :-)....Now I have edited your good answer. +1.

Comment: That was a good $\LaTeX$ exercise..phew!

Comment: @sai-kartik Thanks

Comment: My pleasure,@Paras

Comment: (+1) Very nice. Thank you for the efforts.

Comment: @Ali shather Welcome Ali.I hope you like it